# Tabular p-column and environment gives strange output

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

The code below does produce a clearly too high column. The same effect can also be seen with other environments (center, ...).

[image: first column to high]

**How can I use the p-column and have the correct height at the same time?**

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{8cm}|}
    \hline
    A &%
    \begin{lstlisting}
[1.67007,1.99831e-06,0.000413824]
    \end{lstlisting} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|l|}
    \hline
    A &%
    \begin{lstlisting}
[1.67007,1.99831e-06,0.000413824]
    \end{lstlisting} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A better question is to ask why use `listings` in this case?

Comment: @daleif: Of course this is just a MWE. Nevertheless this problem still exists when using `listings` with complex code in complex tables.

Comment: Even in complex cases, why are you having `listings` inside tables? That is probably not the best solution.

Comment: I found it to be the best solution for doing some comparisons (pro and con, side by side) that need to give some descriptions to the code. When using `\lstinline` it seems like another font is used (smaller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work around is to specify `aboveskip` and `belowskip` to be minus the document pointsize and minus the baselineskip, respectively:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{8cm}|}
    \hline
    A &%
    \begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=-10pt,belowskip=-\baselineskip]
[1.67007,1.99831e-06,0.000413824]
    \end{lstlisting} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|l|}
    \hline
    A &%
    \begin{lstlisting}
[1.67007,1.99831e-06,0.000413824]
    \end{lstlisting} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my case (currently writing my thesis) setting only `belowskip` has been sufficient to deal with the problem.

Comment: In the above code the `aboveskip` is necessary.  May be you have some parameters set elsewhere in your document.